# Question about the best way for structuring website directories?

Tags: seo, breadcrumbs, link-building, directory

I am designing my Wordpress website directories and url structure,
my website is a listing of doctors. 
I have a review section for collecting user reviews as a single post that can indexed by google, doctor's profile and medical procedures landing pages (I will show reviews for each procedure inside its landing page)
Which of these path are the best structure for my website:

1. Home > reviews > rhinoplasty reviews > review title
2. Home> procedures > rhinoplasty > reviews

Comment: It really depends on what criteria you're using to judge the "best" way to structure things. Typically you should structure for the most intuitive user experience. You might also be concerned about SEO. For both of those cases, I would recommend not making reviews a separate indexable post type, but instead include them within whatever the reviews are about. Then make sure to include Schema.org markup so those reviews are also recognized as reviews by search engines. That way users find both info about the (thing that's reviewed) as well as reviews all on one page.

Comment: The only reason Cause separate these two, is making review page url shorter, because it is user generated content and the title usually is not short(title of review),

Answer (score 0):

option 2 (Home> procedures > rhinoplasty > reviews)  because it will be beter for SEO and fewer pages have to load, and more specific, and if you want people to share it do you want example.com/item1/item2/item3 or item4/artical or do you want
example.com/item1/item2/item3/artical?